# Changing from Django form to ReactJS

Tags: django, reactjs, django-forms

Currently I have a django sign up form rendered with a django template. I'm starting to switch to ReactJS so I wanted to change that form to a Modal window rendered with react.

The modal will replace the form so it will contain a form in its body containing the same input fields as the django form, before starting i need to know if the modal will work the same as the form or do I need to do some changes like binding it to the django view.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this setup now for the frontend of one project. This is far from trivial and took me some days to figure out. Start with this [webpack-django library](https://github.com/ezhome/django-webpack-loader). You will need to setup your paths carefully along the road. Also for decent development experience, you will need to run webpack in watch mode as the rendering is dealt by django server, not webpack-dev-server (I run this mode in the start script of packages.json). After you can make this work, you will have some obstacles like: csrf tokens and confilct of urls.py with react-routing.

Well, I'm not being more speficic because not sure if you want to follow down this road. Also it requires a tutorial on setting up npm, webpack,django that would raise tons of questions. Besides, I would not recommend doing this just for a login form. You can give up on django forms and build your modal in vanilla javascript/html/css using django's template engine and [bootstrap](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/).

Hope this helps!